What is the command I should use to send a gzipped drive image for extraction to the disk of a remote server?
I have some gzipped files I want to transfer to a remote server and extract directly onto the target drive.
It is similar to this command
dd if=/dev/sda bs=5M conv=fsync status=progress | gzip -c -9 | ssh user@DestinationIP 'gzip -d | dd of=/dev/sda bs=5M'

From this question on Server Fault.
In my case the file is already compressed so the gzip -9 on the source will not be necessary.
It would be more along the lines of:
load-some-file /drive/image.tar.gz | ssh user@DestinationIP 'gzip -d | dd of=/dev/sda bs=5M'

What command should load-some-file be?
Will a command like cat suffice, or will dd itself do?
Can the output of dd be sent to the ssh command directly?

You can name any file image.tar.gz, but if this .tar.gz suffix means the image is tarred and then gzipped then you're missing tar -x on the remote side. But tar -x is not designed to work in the middle of a pipeline; and it makes no sense to tar a single image of a disk in the first place. Your first command looks quite sane, but the second one (the one with image.tar.gz) does not.

Coming to think of it, I didn't use tar to create the file. I have just gotten into the habit of tar.gz from old times when it involves files but in this case the image was created directly from the device.

If your image.tar.gz is something you got from dd … | gzip -c or so, then your second command is as sane as the first, it's just the name of the file what is misleading (image.gz would be better).

"Will a command like cat suffice, or will dd itself do?" - I recommend against dd for this; dd is hard to use, easy to mess up, and often performs subtoptimal. Plain cat would certainly work, but I'd recommend pv which is basically "cat with a progress bar".


What command should load-some-file be?

No command at all. Make ssh itself read the file, i.e. redirect its input:
</drive/image.tar.gz ssh …


Will a command like cat suffice?

cat /drive/image.tar.gz | ssh … or </drive/image.tar.gz cat | ssh … should work, but this is a useless use of cat.
Side note: the form sudo cat /drive/image.tar.gz | ssh … is a good idea when you need elevated access in order to open the file. Here the elevated cat will open and read the file. Redirection with < works by the shell opening the file and setting it up as stdin (i.e. passing the right descriptor) for the tool to read. In this case even </drive/image.tar.gz sudo … would not work because the unelevated shell would be denied access when trying to open the file in the first place. Compare to this answer (it's about output redirection, stdout, but the mechanics is the same).

or will dd itself do? Can the output of dd be sent to the ssh command directly?

Yes, in principle. There are many commands that can output their input as-is, see this answer. Still, if you just want ssh to get the file on its stdin then input redirection will be enough.

How would the command be from the other end, along the lines of rsync user@source:/image.gz | gzip -d | dd of=/dev/sda bs=5M? Is there some other command required before the first | character?

@vfclists Where did this rsync come from? Are you asking what ssh … is in my answer?

I understand your answer. I just want to see how the command will look like if it is executed from the receiving server, so it would have to be rsync, scp or something similar to get the image from the remote server.

@vfclists From the receiving side it may be ssh user@source '<image.gz cat' | gzip -d >/dev/sda. This assumes you can write to /dev/sda.

I generally use /dev/sdXX for examples. In case someone wants to copy/paste and edit it to the correct device name they want to overwrite, it's better if there's never a moment where an accidental newline / enter could overwrite a device that probably does exist.  I guess @vfclists did use sda in the question, but that would also be better as sdXX, IMO, and other future readers might copy/paste a comment.

@PeterCordes I know, I do it sometimes, but it's hard for me to always treat fellow users as children with root access. But frankly, if someone (1) disregards "this assumes you can write to /dev/sda" (i.e. does not think "/dev/sda contains precious data, therefore I shall not allow myself to write to it; I cannot write to it") and (2) pastes the snippet as-is (3) and hits Enter, (4) all this while working in root's shell (as >/dev/sda will not work for regular user, even with sudo), what are the chances that ssh user@source '<image.gz cat' will give him or her any data?

Chances are low but non-zero of accidentally fat-fingering enter in a dangerous situation.  Of course people can and should be more careful when copy/pasting, like not pasting a command with the wrong device into a root shell in the first place, without quotes.  (But note that sudo doesn't help with redirects so it's not unlikely that someone would actually use a root shell for this.)  Using a placeholder devname doesn't make examples any worse, and IMO is the best practice for answers / comments in cases like this.  It's another layer in the "swiss cheese" safety model to prevent accidents.

@PeterCordes "Using a placeholder devname doesn't make examples any worse" – It depends; sometimes, for some users it is confusing. E.g. why would you use sdXX here and not sdX? Is this a suggestion for the OP to write to a partition? And why X, not x? I have never seen a /dev/sd* file with capital letters. It's not a theoretical concern, I was genuinely confused by /dev/sda0. It seems to me we are both right. I'm not against adding layers of cheese, within reason. Sadly a user with rodent's brain will always bite through. :)

To nitpick, it will not be ssh reading the file; the shell will read the file and feed it to the ssh process as standard input. This difference will become significant e.g. when sudo is needed to access the file.

@Imre The shell will open the file and it will set it as stdin for the newly created ssh process. The shell will not relay the content of the file, ssh will read from the file by itself.

Ok yeah I'd normally use sdX, a single letter.  IDK why I went for XX here.  Capital because that clearly marks it as a placeholder, not a real device name.  If I wanted two separate devices, I'd use sdX and sdY.  If I was talking about a hypothetical partition, I might use sdX2 , IDK, as long as part of the device name is a placeholder.  sda0 would be a confusing choice.  Anyway, sorry to fill up the comments with this tangent. >.<  Agreed that nothing is foolproof, but avoiding live ammunition like actual device names (especially sda or nvme0n1) is a good habit.

Fewer footguns are better- since a generic example by necessity doesn't know which device is used sdX (etc) is better tho it is complicated when dealing with specifics like OP's use of sda- was theirs a placeholder or were they really doing an sda-to-sda transfer?

@KamilMaciorowski I notice that there are no spaces between the > and < characters and the file names. Would spaces change the meanings?

@vfclists Spaces would not change the meanings. The answer I have already advised you to see contains an example with a remark "extra spaces allowed".

@Imre Somebody agreed with your comment and it's sad, because it's a myth the input redirection works due to the shell reading the file. In Linux run </dev/null ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 and you will see the stdin of this ls is exactly /dev/null, not some pipe through which the shell would feed the file to ls (if ls ever bothered to read it). Compare this to cat /dev/null | ls -l /proc/self/fd/0. Here cat reads the file and feeds it to the next program. A shell, when setting up redirections, does not work this way.

@KamilMaciorowski I think we both have a valid point. Indeed, the read operations are performed by the executed process, but before that the shell needs to open the file descriptor for reading. For that, the shell process needs read permission to access the file. For example, if bar.txt is not readable for shell, sudo grep foo < bar.txt will not work, but sudo grep foo bar.txt will - the difference being which process opens the file descriptor. A wording like "Make the shell open the file and pass its handle to ssh for reading" would help avoid new myths. Thanks for bringing this up!

@Imre I know about sudo. Answer expanded.
